# Problem in BETWEEN and LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

How can I edit this query to work correctly ?

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 BETWEEN LIKE '%T'  AND LIKE '%t';
```

thanks

Comment: Give me strength!: What doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly this query should do?

Comment: I want to extract rows that they are between ro regular expression.

Comment: @woody What do you mean by saying "between ro regular expression"?

Comment: @woody Perhaps you can give us sample data before and after the query?

Comment: I want to extract rows that they are between two regular expression in this case '%T' AND '%t"

Comment: @woody The problem is that we don't understand what is between '%T' AND '%t". Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: Have you tried my answer ? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, yokoloko ,your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @woody: So column1 should ends up by "T" or "t" letter?

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would be helpful to understand what you want.

Comment: Suppose , I have a column in my table and in that column there is string like 'amir; , 'home' , tablet' 'compleX' . I want to extract those string that last their character is between 'T' and 't'. in my example all names except 'compleX'

Comment: @woody What characters are between T and t?

Comment: @woody: strange but why 'e' is between t and T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want something like this -

**EDITed:**

```
SELECT column1  FROM my_table
WHERE ORD(RIGHT(column1, 1)) >= ORD('T') AND ORD(RIGHT(column1, 1)) <= ORD('t')
```

Comment: One could even bring in `BETWEEN`: `WHERE ORD(RIGHT(column1, 1)) BETWEEN ORD('t') AND ORD('T')`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 LIKE '%T%t';
```

Comment: I thought he wanted to have something between T and t. but maybe I misunderstood the question or maybe the question is not really clear and can have several answers